# Sending email - 1st time contact form creation

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

I'm near concluding my first time creating a custom contact form. I've got everything ready - all I need is the php/ajax code. After googling arround, this is what I've got:

Input fields (HTML file):

```
<label for="userName">Name:</label>
<input id="userName" class="inputField" type="text" name="userName"/>

<label for="userEmail">E-mail:</label>
<input id="userEmail" class="inputField" type="text" name="userEmail"/>

<label for="userSubject">Subject:</label>
<input id="userSubject" class="inputField" type="text" name="userSubject"/>

<label for="userMessage">Message:</label>
<textarea id="userMessage" class="inputField" rows="" cols="" name="userMessage" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>

<label for="userSubject">Assunto:</label>
<input id="userSubject" class="inputField" type="text" name="userSubject"/>
```

My button is an animated function (**not a** `<input type="button"/>`).

PHP file (send.php):

```
<?php

    // Main Variables Used Throughout the Script
    $domain = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // Root Domain - http://example.com
    $siteName = "wwwnovaplaquemar.pt";
    $siteEmail = "guida.e.pedro@gmail.com";
    $er = "";

    // Check if the web form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST["userEmail"])){
        // Process the web form variables
        // Strip out any malicious attempts at code injection, just to be safe.
        // All that is stored is safe html entities of code that might be submitted.
        $userName = htmlentities(substr($_POST["userName"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
        $userEmail = htmlentities(substr($_POST["userEmail"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
        $userSubject = htmlentities(substr($_POST["userSubject"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
        $userMessage = htmlentities(substr($_POST["userMessage"], 0, 10000), ENT_QUOTES);


        // Perform some logic on the form data
        // If the form data has been entered incorrectly, return an Error Message

            // Prepare the E-mail elements to be sent
            $subject = $userSubject;
            $message = 
            '<html>
                <head>
                <title>' . $siteName . ': A Contact Message</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                ' . wordwrap($userMessage, 100) . '
                </body>
            </html>';

            // We are sending the E-mail using PHP's mail function
            // To make the E-mail appear more legit, we are adding several key headers
            // You can add additional headers later to futher customize the E-mail

            $to = $siteName . ' Contact Form <' . $siteEmail . '>';

            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            // Additional Headers
            $headers .= 'From: ' . $userName . ' <' . $userEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $userName . ' <' . $userEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $userName . ' <' . $userEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Date: ' . date("r") . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'X-Mailer: ' . $siteName . "\r\n";

            // And now, mail it
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                echo '<div>Thank you for contacting ' . $siteName . '. We will read your message and contact you if necessary.</div>';
            }
            else {
                $er .= 'We weren&#39;t able to send your message. Please contact ' . $siteEmail . '.<br />';
            }
    }

?>
```

In my js file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send_pt.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      $('#inputText_infoBox p').html("A enviar e-mail...");
    }
  });
```

Question: where do I put what?

Comment: Please stop offering email spamming scripts. Thank you!

Comment: @hakre, care to offer a better one? This IS my first time...

Comment: Sure. Think about it: If you allow the user to specify the email to send an email to in the webform, one can use that form to send emails to everywhere without using it's own computer. Instead think about how you can reduce the allowed mail addresses to a sane minimum.

Comment: Right. I'm a rookie at php. Could you point me in the right direction? Code, tutorial... accessible to a rookie?

Comment: That's less with the technical details but more to think about which (and how) data gets passed.

Comment: I'm checking this [tutorial](http://www.phpnerds.com/article/building-a-secure-contact-form). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

assuming the click event is calling the ajax function..you need to send data to server using `data` in ajax..serialize your form with [jquery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)..this will post all the form elements to the server

try this

```
 $.ajax({
  ...
 data: $('#yourFormID').serialize(),
 success: function(){
  ...
```

Comment: Thanx for the feedback. I made the changes - how can I test if it works? Only through the server... right?

Comment: I ended seeing one other tutorial. I updated the code in my original post.